# How to configure Intellij for Tabs to Spaces for Only Certain File types

Tags: intellij-idea

Most file types I want to have tabs converted to spaces.  However not in Markdown.  I went to the Markdown specific File type and see only limited ability to customize it.  Is there some way to define filetype-specific editing behavior in Intellij?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ normally allows you to set indentation settings per language in *Code style* section of the settings. As far as I know Markdown is not included out of the box and support for it must be installed via plugin. But the plugin doesn't seem to enable Code style configuration for Markdown.

So the only solution I can think of is to set tabs as default indentation in General section of Code style settings and then override it to spaces for individual languages (but that may not be necessary because the code style settings for individual languages will have spaces as default).

One downside of this is that if you work with some filetype other than Markdown which is not natively supported in IntelliJ, it will use tabs even though you might want to use spaces for that filetype.

Alternatively you could create feature request for this functionality either in IntelliJ or the Markdown plugin itself.

Comment: Nice answer - i care about java, scala, and python and should be able to  customize those as you suggest - while using the general case to apply to the unconfigurable Markdown

Comment: Glad it worked for you! By the way, I just thought of a solution which might be better for you - EditorConfig (http://editorconfig.org/). IntelliJ supports it via plugin and you can set your formatting preferences per filetype (extension). So if you run into any limitations with the solution above, give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org) can do what you want. Just add a file `.editorconfig` to the root directory of your IntellJ project. The following `.editorconfig` example will set all files by default to use the 4-character-wide tab character as the indentation, and then a list of other files (and everything in the directory `dir2`) to use 2 spaces as the indentation.

```
#top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4

[{File1.ext,dir1/file2.ext,dir2/*}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

The file matching format is pretty versatile.

IntelliJ IDEA (and some other JetBrain products) should have this installed by default with no need for a plugin. Others may need a plugin.

I would personally recommend adding these other configs for general compatibility and cleanliness

```
[*]
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

Answer (score 2):

I used it as a workaround, `Editor->Code Style->Other File Types`